# Real time flood data in the United States

Tags: open-data, flooding

I am trying to find real time information about flood events in the United States, ideally in polygon format. So far I have found two sources:

- USGS Flood Watch: Points where flood sensors are and the current measurements. This seems comprehensive, but does not contain polygons.
- NOAA Weather Warnings: Polygons of flood watch areas, but I don't believe this is comprehensive of all parts of the United States.

Are there other polygon datasets in real time? I'd like to know observed flood events.